# Populate datagridview combobox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the following code on my windows form load:

```
    private void Panou_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string>[] list;

        //list in a array with all elements from a select query
        list = Conexiune.Select();


        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count; i++)
        {
            int number = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = list[0][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[1].Value = list[1][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[2].Value = list[2][i];

            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[4].Value = list[4][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[5].Value = list[5][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[6].Value = list[6][i];
        }
    }
```

On my datagridview the 4th cell is a combobox. How can I populate the combobox with the value from my select (list[3][i] variable)?

**UPDATE 1:**

```
    private void Panou_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string>[] list;

        list = Conexiune.Select();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();


        for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count; i++)
        {
            int number = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = list[0][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[1].Value = list[1][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[2].Value = list[2][i];
            (dataGridView1.Columns[3] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = new List<string> { list[3][i] };
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[4].Value = list[4][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[5].Value = list[5][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[6].Value = list[6][i];
        }
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WLDr.jpg

**UPDATE 2:**

```
    private void Panou_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string>[] list;

        list = Conexiune.Select();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        (dataGridView1.Columns[3] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = new List<string> { "", "activ", "inactiv", "neverificat" };

        for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count; i++)
        {
            int number = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = list[0][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[1].Value = list[1][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[2].Value = list[2][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[3].Value = list[3][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[4].Value = list[4][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[5].Value = list[5][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[6].Value = list[6][i];
        }
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlnER.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a DataSource for the comboBox column

```
(dataGridView1.Columns[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource 
 = new List<string> { "Apples", "Oranges", "Grapes"};    

     for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count; i++)
    {
        int number = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = list[3][i]; //list[3][1]=="Apples"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good start, Thabk you. I encountered: datagridviewcomboboxcell value is not valid and I solved with private void dataGridView1_DataError . This is correct? The second problem is that the combobox appear with first Item 1 but if a click wont dropdown.

Comment: It shouldn't give you a DataError. Can I know what your DataSource for the ComboBox column is?

Comment: (dataGridView1.Columns[3] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = new List<string> { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3"};

Comment: Ah thats the problem . Replace "Item1" "Item2" "Item3" with the actual values you want the comboBox to show.

Comment: Please read the update of my question. Even if I have  "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" the combobox won`t dropdown. I press the combobox and did not drop down.

Comment: No that's not right. The DataSource code should be outside the for loop as I have given in my answer. Just replace "Item1" etc with your values. btw whats the value of list[3][1]?

Comment: I've made a edit to my code above.The "DataSource" contains the possible values that can be selected from the comboBox, in this case lets say Apples,Oranges and Grapes. Now your list[3][i] 's value has to be either "Apples" "Oranges" or "Grapes" . Hope you got it

Comment: list[3][i] - is i from for not the number 1. List is a select from database that returns 300 values and must be 300 comboboxes. Because of this I included in the loop. I uploaded a screenshot to post update.

Comment: What are the possible values for Status Cont?

Comment: Well I almost understand the logic of the code: I have the values from the database in the comboboxes like they are in database. Almost done, the single problem that I have now is when I press on a combobox on the windows form does not drop down. See screenshot 2.

Comment: I did. See UPDATE 2. Now I understand what is data source.

Comment: Thank you, I marked as a answer. Maybe you can help me here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965652/datagridview1-rowsremoved-not-working-as-i-expect